# Selecting random String from .plist?

Tags: objective-c, random, uilabel

I am currently new to developing and have run into a problem. I would like to read string from a .plist and when a button is pressed it picks a random string and presents it in a label? I have a sample .plist and a button instantiated in my .h and .m however I just don't know how to select a random string and change the UILabels value to the selected string. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance!.

Heres my .plist[image]

And here is my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController  {
IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
}

-(IBAction)randomButton;
```

And here is my .m

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

//What do I put in my randomButton method to extract from .plist?
-(IBAction)randomButton {
}
```

Comment: i think the problem is to read plist file. See this [tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/reading-a-plist-into-an-nsarray.html). Then generate a random number i with arc4random() and set UILabel's text as the i-th element of readed NSArray

Comment: sorry medvedNick i was talking to H2..

Comment: Using a plist to select a random string?  You must be kidding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all you should rearrange you plist file, so all the strings are in one array (now your strings are not in "words" array). If so, read plist into NSArray:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
     @"my" ofType:@"plist"]; 

NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *plistArray = plistDict[@"words"];
```

then, generate random variable:

```
int randV = arc4random() % plistArray.count; // randV is from 0 to number of strings -1 in array
```

then, set label's text:

```
label1.text = plistArray[randV];
```

also, I highly recommend to read some books or go through a few tutorials before asking questions like that.

Comment: Ok, i did as above, however when i press the button the label just goes blank, is it a problem with my .plist, its located in the supporting files folder, is that ok?

Comment: @RobertSaunders drag all your strings into "words" array in plist file

Comment: k, have done that and now have 4 items in the words array but still nothing

Comment: @RobertSaunders I hope you've changed the name of plist in the first line? you can NSLog(@"dictionary: %@, array: %@", plistDict, plistArray) to see if they are read correctly

Comment: Hey, thanks very much, i got it to work, I missed one line of code.